# expire session when there is no activity in PHP

Tags: php, session, cookies, session-variables, session-cookies

I found many tutorials on Internet when you expire a session after a certain limit, like after 30 minutes or so, But I want to expire a session when there is no activity,
quoting from a famous SO question [the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1270960/1091386) is straight forward:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY']) 
    && (time() - $_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] > 1800)) {
        // last request was more than 30 minutes ago
        session_unset();     // unset $_SESSION variable for the run-time 
        session_destroy();   // destroy session data in storage
    }
$_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] = time(); // update last activity time stamp
```

but do I have to update the `$_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY']` on each request?

The pre-assumed answer is Yes, but I have a big site containing 200+ php pages and it's hectic to update `$_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY']` on each request.

Is there any other way of doing this? The only common thing among all files is one config file for DB connection.

Comment: Search for every occurrence of `session_start()` and add the code after that. Better: Push your code snippet into a function or better a class and only call that class.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could also update the `$_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY']` only (eg) once per minute but than the session will not be destroyed after exactly 30 minutes.

```
if (isset($_SESSION["LAST_ACTIVITY"])) {
    if (time() - $_SESSION["LAST_ACTIVITY"] > 1800) {
        // last request was more than 30 minutes ago
        session_unset();     // unset $_SESSION variable for the run-time 
        session_destroy();   // destroy session data in storage
    } else if (time() - $_SESSION["LAST_ACTIVITY"] > 60) {
        $_SESSION["LAST_ACTIVITY"] = time(); // update last activity time stamp
    }
}
```

And the easiest way to do this is put the code in the config file since I don't think you want to change all 200 php files.

Comment: This will not work if you have `session_write_close()` (required to support concurrent ajax requests) enabled.

Comment: extra right bracket, please fix it
if (time() - $_SESSION["LAST_ACTIVITY"] > 1800)) {

Answer (score 1):

Corrected syntax..

```
if (isset($_SESSION["LAST_ACTIVITY"])) {
    if ((time() - $_SESSION["LAST_ACTIVITY"]) > 1800) {        
        // last request was more than 30 minutes ago
        session_unset();     // unset $_SESSION variable for the run-time 
        session_destroy();   // destroy session data in storage    
    } else if (time() - $_SESSION["LAST_ACTIVITY"] > 60) {    
        $_SESSION["LAST_ACTIVITY"] = time(); // update last activity time stamp    
    }
}
```